# Ajax request don't start immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i stop this from autoplaying, I have a search button and I want to search first before getting the data, any approach is okay to me, whether it's AJAX side or Javascript side, please help.

**Javascript**

```
var table = $('#SARDatatable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-2'i><'col-sm-5'B><'col-sm-5'p>>",
    buttons: [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5',
        'print'
    ],
    "ajax": {
        "url": '/Home/GetAllSAR',
        "type": "POST",
        "datatype": "json",
        "data": function (d) {
            d.searchParameters = {};
            d.searchParameters.sarcode = $('#txtSAR').val();
            d.searchParameters.stype = $('#txtSType').val();
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "sarcode", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "stype", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "amount", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "filterno", "autoWidth": true }
    ]
});

$('#btnSearch').on("click", function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Agreed. The question is _unclear_. What exactly is it you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to only initialize the table after a button has been clicked, so that the AJAX request to get the data will not be issued before clicking the button.

If this is the case, then I would suggest the following:

1. Have a button that inits the table:

**HTML**

```
<button id='initTable'>Init Table</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var table;
$('#initTable').on('click', function() {
    table = $('#SARDatatable').DataTable({ // code to init the DataTable });
});
```

2. Have the 'reload' button

**HTML**

```
<button id='btnSearch'>Reload</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#btnSearch').on("click", function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
});
```

After you init the table, you can hide the "Init Table" button, so that there will be only one button at a time.

Hope this helps.